# How to merge two lists of maps in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have data in below format.

```
'(({:nums {:test number?, :data (1)}})
  {:Other ()} 
  ({:nums {:test number?, :data (2)}})
  ({:nums {:test number?, :data (3 4)}}))
```

But I would like to get data in below format.

```
'(({:nums {:test number?, :data (1 2 3 4)}}) 
  {:Other ()})
```

Tried with merge, union functions, but not worked. 
Could you please help here as I am beginner to Closure.

**Doing tests on below code**

```
(split '(1 2 (3 4 [1 2 3])) {:nums {:test number?}})
=> 
((({:nums {:test number?, :data (1)}}) {:Other ()})
  (({:nums {:test number?, :data (2)}}) {:Other ()})
  (({:nums {:test number?, :data (3 4)}}) {:Other (([1 2 3]))}))
```

**But The target result I am expecting as below**

```
(split '(1 2 (3 4 [1 2 3])) {:nums {:test number?}})
=> 
(({:nums {:test number?, :data (1 2 3 4)}}) 
 {:Other ([1 2 3])})
```

**Code used:**

```
(defn test
  [list1 filter1]
  ;(get-in (first (first (split list1 filter1))) [:nums :test])
  (first (first (split list1 filter1))))

(defn split [list1 filter_map]
  (if (empty? list1)
    ()
    (cons (split_list
            (if (sequential? (first list1))
              (first list1)
              (list (first list1)))
            filter_map)
      (split (rest list1) filter_map))))

(defn split_list [list1 filter_map]
  (let [var_in_filter (remove nil? (in-filter filter_map))
        var_out_filter (remove nil? (out-filter filter_map))]
    ;var_out_filter
    (list (in_filter_recur list1 var_in_filter)
      ;(in_filter_recur list1  var_in_filter)
      (hash-map :Other (remove nil?
                         (out_filter_recur list1 var_out_filter))))))

(defn in_filter_recur [lis in_filt]
  (if (empty? in_filt)
    nil
    (cons (hash-map
            (if ((first in_filt) 1)
              :nums
              ;"{:nums {:test number?}"
              (if ((first in_filt) 'a)
                :syms
                (if ((first in_filt) [1])
                  :vects
                  'others)))

            ;(set (merge [:data] (filter (first in_filt) lis))))
            (hash-map :test
              (if ((first in_filt) 1)
                'number?
                ;"{:nums {:test number?}"
                (if ((first in_filt) 'a)
                  'symbols?
                  (if ((first in_filt) [1])
                    'vector?
                    'others)))
              :data (filter (first in_filt) lis)))
      (in_filter_recur lis (rest in_filt)))))

(defn out_filter_recur [lis out_filt]
  (if (empty? out_filt)
    nil
    (cons ;(hash-map nil
      (if (empty? (filter (first out_filt) lis))
        nil
        (filter (first out_filt) lis))
      (out_filter_recur lis (rest out_filt)))))

(defn out-filter [filt]
  (difference 
    (set 
      (All-filter
        {:nums {:test number?}
         :syms {:test symbol?}
         :vects {:test vector?}
         :other {:test string?}})) (set (in-filter filt))))

(defn in-filter [filt]
  (list (when
          (and (> (count (str (get-in filt [:nums :test]))) 0)
            ((get-in filt [:nums :test]) 1))
          number?)
    (when
      (and (> (count (str (get-in filt [:syms :test]))) 0)
        ((get-in filt [:syms :test]) 'a))
      symbol?)
    (when
      (and (> (count (str (get-in filt [:vects :test]))) 0)
        ((get-in filt [:vects :test]) [1]))
      vector?)))



(defn All-filter [filt]
  (list (when
          (and (> (count (str (get-in filt [:nums :test]))) 0)
            ((get-in filt [:nums :test]) 1))
          number?)
    (when
      (and (> (count (str (get-in filt [:syms :test]))) 0)
        ((get-in filt [:syms :test]) 'a))
      symbol?)
    (when
      (and (> (count (str (get-in filt [:vects :test]))) 0)
        ((get-in filt [:vects :test]) [1]))
      vector?)
    (when
      (and (> (count (str (get-in filt [:other :test]))) 0)
        ((get-in filt [:other :test]) "1"))
      string?)))


(defn difference
  ([s1] s1)
  ([s1 s2]
   (if (< (count s1) (count s2))
     (reduce (fn [result item]
               (if (contains? s2 item)
                 (disj result item)
                 result))
       s1 s1)
     (reduce disj s1 s2)))
  ([s1 s2 & sets]
   (reduce difference s1 (conj sets s2))))
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed so we can improve from there.

Comment: More important even than that, what the actual goal is, better specs. There are lots of potential algorithms that could produce this output from the given input, which would behave differently for various inputs.

Comment: Hi Amalloy, I added code now. Please suggest me how to get target result.

Comment: Could you first explain why your data is in this weird shape. Could it be possible to change it's shape ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, it's kind of a specific data structure, so it's pretty specific code

The first step is to set up the data so that we can work with `merge-with`

```
(defn get-data [val]
  (as-> val ?
        (first ?)
        (:nums ?)
        (select-keys ? [:data])))
```

Then the last step is to call `merge-with` and put it back together

```
(def x '(({:nums {:test number?, :data (1)}})
         {:Other ()} 
         ({:nums {:test number?, :data (2)}})
         ({:nums {:test number?, :data (3 4)}}))

(as-> x ? 
      (map get-data ?)
      (apply merge-with concat ?)
      (assoc ? :test 'number?)
      (list ?)
      (list ?)
      (conj ? {:Other '()})
      (reverse ?))
```

If you were looking for something more generic, you'll have to come at me with a more generic data structure.

I think what you were looking for is mostly contained in the `(apply merge-with concat ?)` line which does most of the work.

This function takes a list of maps and applies the function, in this case `concat` to the values in those maps.

See `(doc merge-with)` in your REPL for more information.

As a last ditch effort, you may also be interested in the [specter](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter) clojure library which excels at this sort of deeply nested data transformation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked with ``` (apply merge-with into flatten '(list')) ```